# Issue with namespaced classes loading sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two namespaced classes. One of them inherits other.

Directory structure is as follows:

```
app
└── clients
    └── test
        ├── a
        │   └── calls
        │       └── reports.rb
        ├── b
        │   └── calls
        │       └── reports.rb
        ├── c
        │   └── calls
        │       └── reports.rb
        ├── a.rb
        ├── b.rb
        └── c.rb
```

Here is code snippet:

```
# app/clients/test/c/calls/reports.rb
module Test::C::Calls
  class Reports < Test::B::Calls::Reports
  end
end

# app/clients/test/b/calls/reports.rb
module Test::B::Calls
  class Reports < Test::A::Calls::Reports
  end
end

# app/clients/test/a/calls/reports.rb
module Test::A::Calls
  class Reports
  end
end

# app/clients/test/a.rb
class Test::A 
end

# app/clients/test/b.rb
class Test::B < Test::A  
end

# app/clients/test/c.rb
class Test::C < Test::B  
end
```

On rails console, If `Test::B::Calls::Reports` is called before `Test::C::Calls::Reports` then `Test::C::Calls::Reports` is returning `Test::B::Calls::Reports` but, vice versa is working fine.

I am using rails 4.1.4.

I am not able to find out issue.

Comment: _"Test::C::Calls::Reports is returning Test::B::Calls::Reports"_ – the constant is referring to the wrong class?

Comment: Yes. you are right.

Comment: @Stefan : any luck?

Comment: Not really, no. Based on your code I don't see how a constant could refer to a different / wrong class.